# Compile Error: for each control variable must be variant or object

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I get error:

> Compile Error: for each control variable must be variant or object

I am trying to:
Open a file from a list in Excel (Path, filename and extension in Column A),
then copy specific account info from the corresponding row (Column D) to a specified cell in the opened file,
save the file as a new filename (with extension specified in Column C),
close then go to next row and repeat.

This is code. Do I need to set the size of the data list?

```vb
Sub CM_Details()

Dim wb1 As Workbook 'Details
Dim wb2 As Workbook 'New CM
Dim i As Long   'row
Dim rng As Range

Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
Set rng = Range("A2", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

With wb1
    For Each i In rng
        If .Sheets("Detail").Range("A" & i).Value <> "" Then

            Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(.Sheets("Detail").Range("A" & i).Value)

            wb1.Sheets("Detail").Range("D" & i).Copy    'RoC
            wb2.Sheets("Home").Range("B1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            Application.CutCopyMode = False

            wb2.SaveAs Filename:="R:\ASSL v4\" & wb1.Sheets("Detail").Range("C" & i).Value
            wb2.Close

        End If
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: The control variable is 'i'.  You have declared i as a long.  For 'for each' loops the 'i' (control variable) must be declared either as a variant or as an object of the same type as will be delivered by the iterated collection/array (rng).  Try reading the manual/help pages.  It usually helps a lot with these type of  errors.

Comment: Also, when you `Set rng =` specify the Workbook on all 3 range objects  as you have elsewhere in the code

Comment: @chris neilsen - thanks, I am not a particularly advanced user so not entirely sure how to reference things like "Rng" so I will try this, so it is easier to reuse in future

Comment: @freeflow Thanks for your time - turns out Dim i needed to be integer (for row number), rather than long (I thought it needed to cover the length of the file path contained in column A) so have definitely learned something. I tried plenty of searches to find how to do this, which is how I got this close to a solution. If you can refer an easy-to use manual that would be great

Answer (score 0):

First replace:

```
For Each i In rng
```

with:

```
for i = 2 to Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

then continue your debugging.

Comment: Or, having already set rng, for i = rng.row to rng.row + rng.rows - 1

Comment: @chrisneilsen  Yes....that is a good approach.............if `rng` changes, only one code line will have to change....................thank you!

Comment: @Gary'sStudent thanks, once I fixed Dim i as Integer this has worked - this will save me sooooooo much time :)

Comment: @chrisneilsen thanks for your response - i have tried your suggestion but get "Run time error 13: type mismatch" Now I have something that works I will go with it